# Closed subspace of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

If a set A, say, is closed in a subspace Y of X (say), can one conclude that the set A is always closed in the space X? Or do we have a condition under which A is closed in X as a generalization? If there exists such a condition, please I need to know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When $A\subseteq Y\subseteq X$ and $Y$ is closed in $X$, then $A$ is closed in $Y$ if and only if it is closed in $X$.

However, if $Y$ is not closed in $X$, this is false. For example $A=Y$ is always closed in $Y$.

Comment: You're very correct , it is sufficient to say that A is closed in Y if and only if it is closed in X.

Answer (score 1):

There are two good answers already.

How about a concrete example?

$(0,1)$ is closed in $(0,1)$.  But $(0,1)$ is not closed in $\Bbb R$.

Similarly $(1,2]$ is closed in itself,  but not in $\Bbb R$.

And, back to the first example,  $[1/3,1)$ is closed in $(0,1)$.  But not in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Your counter examples are great!

Comment: Thanks.  They're relatively simple.   But, playing around with these sorts of things can help you understand the subject.

Answer (score 0):

The collection of closed subsets of $Y$ is $\{Y\cap F\mid F\text{ is closed in }X\}$.

One of these sets is $Y$ itself, because $Y=Y\cap X$ and $X$ is closed in $X$.

But of course $Y$ does not have to be closed in $X$.

In the special case where $Y$ is closed in $X$ all members of the collection are - as intersection of two sets both closed in $X$ - closed in $X$.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is incorrect in general. for example, let $ X=\mathbb{R}$  and $Y=[0,1]\cup (2,3)
$. Also let $ A=(2,3)$.
We need to take a look at the following theorems.

${\textbf{Theorem1 :}}$ Assume, $Y\subset X$. For a given $A$ , $A$ is closed( open ) in $Y$, if $A=Y\cap C$ for some $C$ which is closed( open ) in $X$.

${\textbf{Theorem2 :}}$ Assume, $Y\subset X$. For a given $A$ , if $A$ is closed in $Y$ , and $Y$ is closed in $X$ . Then $A$ is closed in $X$.

Now, according to the first theorem , $[0,1]$ is open in $Y$, because one can write $[0,1]= Y\cap (\frac{-1}{2}, \frac{3}{2} ) $. On the other hand, $[0,1]$ and $(2,3)$ are complement in $Y$ and So they are both closed in $Y$.
Now, we have $A=(2,3)$ which is closed in $Y$, while it is open in $X=\mathbb{R}$. This is also a counterexample for the second theorem.

${\textbf{Edit :}}$ Precisely speaking, we have $A=(2,3)$ which is closed in $Y$, while it is not closed in $X=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You might want to replace "… which is closed in $Y$, while it is open in $X$" by "… which is closed in $Y$, while it is *not closed* in $X$". Being open does not contradict being closed!

Comment: Yes, I meant that. And of course, you are right. Thank you for the precise tip.

Comment: Thank you so much for connecting those theorems with examples to buttress your point.